# Displaying value from local storage in Angular Page

Tags: javascript, angular

This should be something trivial but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

**What I need** is an input field that is by default filled out for a user from a value from local Storage.

The problem I've run into is that none of the ways I'd normally do this (jQuery onload, JS onload or a `(onload)` in the HTML tag) seem to be run when a user switches to a different page without reloading. I've also tried `ngOnInit()` but that seems to be running before the page's DOM Content is ready to be edited and isn't working here.

Here is my code:

```
<form (submit)="editName($event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
    <!-- I want to insert the localStorage Value user_name into this input -->
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="nameInput" (onload)="initName()"> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

A sad attempt at acheiving this is also in my component.ts:

```
initName() {
  document.getElementById("nameInput").textContent = localStorage.getItem('user_name');
}
```

The error message in my console is:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_name' of undefined
```

Comment: I don't see why ngOnInit() wouldn't work here - bind the input field's value to a component property, then set this value from local storage in ngOnInit()

Comment: The error you get tells you that there is no such a thing as 'user_name' in local storage. Are you sure you've set it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TS page**

1. init variable
   `username:string;`
2. create function for fill variable from localstorage

`getName(){
this.username = localStorage.getItem("user_name";
}`

3. call variable on page load

`onInit(){
this.getName();
}`

**html page**

`<input type="name" class="form-control" id="nameInput" value="{{username}}">`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an Angular ReactiveForm in this case instead of manually retrieving and binding the value.

In your component, create an instance of a FormGroup and bind the value from localStorage to the form control:

```typescript
@Component({
  template: `
    <form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form" (submit)="editName($event)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
        <input formControlName="name" type="name" class="form-control" id="nameInput"> 
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(localStorage.getItem('user_name')),
    });
  }
}
```

For more on Reactive forms in Angular, see: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Angular Reactive Forms over Template-driven Forms regarding the purpose here. With a Template-driven approach you'll end up setting the localStorage bindings explicitly for every value inside your form. A better alternative is using Reactive Forms. (see Brandon's answer)

Assuming you use a FormGroup for your whole form you can retrieve and save the whole form using the `FormGroup.value` method that will give you all the values of your form in one step without disabled controls or `FormGroup.getRawValue()` to also include disabled controls. You can then just use this to store your attributes in the localStorage on form submit:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    surName: new FormControl('user_surname'),
    name: new FormControl('user_name'),
    age: new FormControl('user_age'),
    ...
});
localStorage.setItem('userFormValues',JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
```

See how this example looks in your local storage:

[image: Show Image]

This way your local storage will not be messed up with many keys. To read your values back to your form just use `JSON.parse` in combination with `FormGroup.setValue()`:

```
this.form.setValue(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userFormValues')));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've gone with creating a method called getUsername() in component.ts:

```
getUsername() {
  return localStorage.getItem('user_name');
}
```

then I bound it to the input using this:

```
<input type="name" class="form-control" id="nameInput" value="{{getUsername()}}">
```